# Springboot application does not start after migrating it from apache tomcat application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to change my existing application which runs on tomcat to SpringBoot. It runs till the actual SpringBoot starts. I have a similar application which runs on springBoot. That is how I know it runs till springboot.

My main method:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Every argument passed needs to become a system property
    for (String arg : args) {
        System.getProperties().setProperty(arg.split("=")[0], arg.split("=")[1]);
    }
    SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
}}
```

POM.xml has the springboot parent tag :

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0.M4</version>
</parent>
```

I have springboot maven plugin :

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
```

properties has the start tag:

```
<start-class>com.sample.requesthandler.Main</start-class>
```

Dependencies has starter-web and starter-acuator:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I tried to run the main method with @componentScan having the basePackages which looks like:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.sample.requesthandler")
```

This did not help.
I tried adding @SpringBootApplication annotation at the top of main class. That did not help too.

Below is the full log:

```
15:59:29,832 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type 
[ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
15:59:29,833 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
15:59:29,833 |-INFO in 
ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming 
default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for 
[encoder] property
15:59:29,834 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [big-sur] to ERROR
15:59:29,834 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [big-sur] to false
15:59:29,834 |-INFO in 
ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender 
named [FILE] to Logger[big-sur]
15:59:29,835 |-INFO in 
ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender 
named [STDOUT] to Logger[big-sur]
15:59:29,835 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [big-sur] to INFO
15:59:29,835 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [big-sur] to false
15:59:29,835 |-INFO in 
ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender 
named [FILE] to Logger[big-sur]
15:59:29,835 |-INFO in 
ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender 
named [STDOUT] to Logger[big-sur]
15:59:29,835 |-INFO in 
ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of 
ROOT logger to INFO
15:59:29,835 |-INFO in 
ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender 
named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
15:59:29,835 |-INFO in 
ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender 
named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
15:59:29,835 |-INFO in 
ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of 
configuration.
15:59:29,835 |-INFO in 
ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@351d00c0 - Registering 
current configuration as safe fallback point
```

My other project starts springBoot right after this line.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a full log? Does it show, for example, the spring boot banner? If so, please post that.

Comment: added complete log to the question. After the last line, it does not load the spring boot banner.

Comment: I don't see anything in the SpringBootApplication that is wrong. Might have to disable your services and see if you can bring up the plain app.

Comment: You do realize that you're missing the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on your main class, right?

Comment: @Makoto I tried that, it did not work. That was my first try.

Comment: For starters stop messing with milestone releases and use version `2.0.1.RELEASE` instead of some pre-release version. Also does it really not start or is it just the logging you don't see. Judging from what you posted here you have a custom `logback.xml` to reconfigure the logging (remove it and see what happens). I'm also intrigued by the fact that you think that every argument needs to be a system property, why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the version，like this

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the logback.xml. It had multiple tags with same format. I have updated the logback.xml and it fixed the issue. Now I am able to start the spring boot application properly.

Thank you every for your time!

Answer (score -1):

Your main class should implement [**CommandLineRunner**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html) interface from Spring Boot.

Comment: remove @Configuration

Comment: It did not work after removing @configuration and implementing CommandLineRunner interface

Comment: No it shouldn't. That is only for command line based jobs or if you want to run some logic. You don't need it for regular applications.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @M.Deinum